# consul - connect client to server

Tags: service, microservices, consul, service-discovery

I'm new at consul and I try to setup a server-client environment. I have started my server with the following command and configuration:

```
consul.exe agent -ui -config-dir=P:\Consule\config
```

The config file looks the following ("P:\Consule\config\server.json")

```
{
    "bootstrap": false,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "MyServices",
    "data_dir": "P:\\Consule\\data",
    "log_level": "INFO"
}
```

Output when I start consul from commandline with above command:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Consul agent running!
       Version: 'v0.8.3'
       Node ID: '1a244456-e725-44be-0549-33603ea7087d'
       Node name: 'MYCOMPUTERNAMEA'
       Datacenter: 'myservices'
       Server: true (bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: 127.0.0.1 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
       Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
       Gossip encrypt: false, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
       Atlas: <disabled>
```

Now, at another computer in my domain I try to run an consul client with follwoing commandline and config-file:

```
consul.exe agent -config-dir C:\Consul -bind=127.0.0.1
```

Config file ("C:\Consul\client.json")

```
{
    "server": false,
    "datacenter": "MyServices",
    "data_dir": "C:\\TEMP",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "start_join": ["MYCOMPUTERNAMEA"]
}
```

But I always get follwing output/error message:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Joining cluster...
==> 1 error(s) occurred:

* Failed to join <IP_OF_MYCOMPUTERNAMEA>: dial tcp <IP_OF_MYCOMPUTERNAMEA>:8301: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the reason is that your server is available only for `127.0.0.1` ip-address, which is `localhost` ip and available only from the same server. This can be seen here:

```
Client Addr: 127.0.0.1 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
```

You have to configure your server, to make it listening all network interfaces or some specific interface, which have to be available from other server.

Try to run it with the `client` and `advertise` options set to `0.0.0.0` (or some specific ip). Read about it [here](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_client) and [here](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_advertise).

And you might have to delete `-bind=127.0.0.1` from the client configuration, since it might be available from the server too.

Comment: Adding `-client=0.0.0.0` when starting the agent did the trick for me.